# Force Bootstrap 4 breakpoint (for preview) by class

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, responsive

Bootstrap 4 CSS uses media queries to get current screen size and display elements in the style of according device (screen width).

But what if I want to show preview of mobile markup on wide screen?

I want something like adding some class "preview-sm":

```
<div class="preview-sm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so all Bootstrap 4 media queries will be overrided by breakpoint I specify in this class.

Is this possible?
Or maybe there is another way to show preview in Bootstrap?

Comment: @media queries are always based on screen width.. they don't work on element width.

Comment: I know, but maybe there is another way to have another breakpoint preview? Maybe some hack in SCSS?

Answer (score 3):

You can break styles by class like that:

```
.preview-sm .container {
   width: 1000px !important;
}
```

But `@media` always based on screen size.

Comment: This will apply width to container only, but still "col-lg-xx" classes will be used inside. But I need to use "col-sm-xx" classes for columns inside of this preview wrap.